# Laravel Dusk + Vue with ElementUI

Tags: laravel, testing, select, laravel-dusk, element-ui

I need help writting test with Laravel Dusk. I'm using Vue with [ElementUI](http://element.eleme.io). I really like this framework, however, I can't use Dusk's build-in `select()` method in my tests.

It's because the [select](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/select) component of ElementUI does not generate a real `<select>` tag, instead, it creates a normal `<input>` (that is readonly) and, at bottom of the page, the popper with select's options, so, there is not a `<select>` tag in my page, only a **`<div>`** and a readonly **`<input>`**.

How can I write a test with Dusk that lets me click on a 'div'??

If I try to type on that input with something like this:

```
// $browser->select('my_select_id'); not working,
$browser->type('my_select_id', 1);
```

It throws me an Exception:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it.
```

So I don't know how to test ElementUI's selects :(

Please help,

Thx!

**Edit**

Posting html generated by ElementUI:

```
    <div class="el-select w-100 el-select--mini" value="0" title="Cliente" dusk="v-select-component">
        <div class="el-input el-input--mini el-input--suffix">
            <input autocomplete="off" placeholder="Cliente" size="mini" name="client_id" id="client_id" readonly="readonly" type="text" rows="2" class="el-input__inner">
            <span class="el-input__suffix">
                <span class="el-input__suffix-inner">
                    <i class="el-select__caret el-input__icon el-icon-arrow-up"></i>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="el-select-dropdown el-popper" style="display: none; min-width: 512.344px;">
            <div class="el-scrollbar" style="">
                <div class="el-select-dropdown__wrap el-scrollbar__wrap" style="margin-bottom: -17px; margin-right: -17px;">
                    <ul class="el-scrollbar__view el-select-dropdown__list" style="position: relative;">
                        <li class="el-select-dropdown__item selected"><span>Item 1</span></li>
                        <li class="el-select-dropdown__item"><span>Item 2</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-horizontal">
                    <div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateX(0%);"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="el-scrollbar__bar is-vertical">
                    <div class="el-scrollbar__thumb" style="transform: translateY(0%);"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Edit 2:**

I added a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfqnr61k/5/) with ElementUI's select example. I simply want to test that select with Laravel Dusk

Comment: Can post the HTML that ElementUI generates for the select component?

Comment: I added. Thx for comment :D

Comment: I've never worked with ElementUI. Can you give me a simple code example (HTML & JS) so I can try to a find solution?

Comment: Or can you create a public test website?

Comment: I added JSFiddle, but I dont know if that's enough. Thx for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to click on the `.el-select` element and wait for the popper to open up:

```
$browser->click('.el-select');
$browser->waitFor('.el-select-dropdown.el-popper');
```

Then you can select an option by index:

```
$browser->elements('.el-select-dropdown__item')[2]->click();
```

Or by text:

```
$selector = "//li[@class='el-select-dropdown__item']/span[text()='Option3']";
$browser->driver->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath($selector))->click();
```

I don't see a way to select options by value, since the values aren't anywhere in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This works only if you only have one el-select on the page when you have multiple there is no way to identify them or add an identifier

Comment: (This post does not seem to provide a [quality answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to the question. Please either edit your answer and improve it, or just post it as a comment to the question.)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: If you have two el-select elements on the page then

 `$browser->waitFor('.el-select-dropdown.el-popper');`

 no longer works. It times out.

`Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeOutException: Waited 5 seconds for selector [body > div.el-select-dropdown.el-popper.is-multiple]`

There is no way to make the selector unique enough. if I remove one of the el-select elements then the above does work.

Comment: @Lionslair , i found a solution with Javascript execution. It's not perfect, but it s useful to complete tests and use multiple `el-select`.

Comment: Maintainer got back to me. Using the popper-class prop allows you to add a unique identifier which worked for me

Answer (score 0):

@Lionslair is right: If you use more than one `el-select` in your page, @JonasStaudenmeir's solution returns error.

To make it works, i use javascript execution. You can add this function in your custom `Browser` or in your `Component` :

```
public function elSelectDropdownClose(Browser $browser)
{
    $browser->script(
<<<EOT
    Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.el-select-dropdown.el-popper:not([style*=\"display: none\"])')).map(function(el){
        el.style.display = 'none'
    })
EOT
    );
}
public function elSelectDropdownClick(Browser $browser, $index)
{
    $browser->script(
<<<EOT
    document.querySelectorAll('.el-select-dropdown.el-popper:not([style*=\"display: none\"]) .el-select-dropdown__item')[$index].click()
EOT
    );
    $this->elSelectDropdownClose($browser);
}
```

To run test :

```
$browser
    ->click('.el-select.first')
    ->elSelectDropdownClick(0);

$browser
    ->click('.el-select.second')
    ->elSelectDropdownClick(2);
```